# Griffon "error injecting constructor" while trying to call loadFromFXML

Tags: javafx, dependency-injection, guice, griffon

I have a series of popups where I edit or view specific objects. I use these popups for editing various objects that are handled by and ORM (ORMLite), what I am trying to achieve is to have a generic/abstract class that implements similar behaviours through encapsulating methods. As I don't want to have the same FXML for all of the
popup dialogs what I came up with was to create a "template" FXML, load it through loadFXML() function provided by Griffon and store it in a Node object to be the root of the created Scene at the Abstract Class. I am familiar with dependency injection, but I am not aware of the AST of the framework so my Abstract class is able to call loadFromFXML() within the Abstract class I created.

I post my code here:

Concrete class implementing the abstract ViewPopUp class I created:

```
    @ArtifactProviderFor(GriffonView.class)
    public class VerConductoresView extends AbstractViewPopUp<ObservablePlanilla> {
    private VerConductoresController controller;
    private ConductoresModel model;

    VerConductoresView() {
        super(ObservablePlanilla.class, Conductor.class);
        nodeM = new GridPane();
        super.setController(controller);
    }


    @Override
    public void initUI() {
        Stage stage = (Stage) getApplication()
            .createApplicationContainer(Collections.<String,Object>emptyMap());
        stage.setTitle(getApplication().getConfiguration().getAsString("application.title"));
        stage.setScene(init());
        stage.sizeToScene();
        getApplication().getWindowManager().attach("ver-conductores", stage);
    }
}
```

Abstract view PopUp I created:

```
public abstract class AbstractViewPopUp<T> extends AbstractJavaFXGriffonView {
    protected Class klazz;
    protected Class<T> klazz2;
    protected Scene viewScene;
    protected ViewControllerPopUp viewController;
    protected TableView tableView;
    protected GridPane gridPane;
    protected String[] ignoredNames;
    protected String[] columnNames;
    protected IModel<T> viewModel;
    protected Node nodeM;

    @MVCMember
    public void setController(ViewControllerPopUp controller) {
        this.viewController = controller;
    }


    AbstractViewPopUp(Class<T> k1, Class k2, Node node){
        klazz = k2;
        klazz2 = k1;
        nodeM = node;
        nodeM = loadFromFXML("com.softgan.viewPopUp");
        nodeM = node;
    }

    AbstractViewPopUp(Class<T> k1, Class k2){
        klazz = k2;
        klazz2 = k1;
        nodeM = loadFromFXML("com.softgan.viewPopUp");
    }

    protected Scene init() {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        if (nodeM instanceof Parent) {
            scene.setRoot((Parent) nodeM);
        } else {
            ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(nodeM);
        }

        connectActions(nodeM, viewController);
        connectMessageSource(nodeM);
        return scene;
    }
}
```

I want to load the FXML through the Abstract class and then store it so the concrete class can access the loaded FXML so I am able to manipulate its contents, adding labels and textfields dynamically. The problem seems to be that loadFromFXML is throwing a NullPointerException as it is not able to resolve the FXML file from the resources. I already tried to use an AST transformation to make it resources aware, but it seems to not be a valid approach as Guice is not able to resolve, I think, the ResourceHandler.

**EDIT**

This is the Stacktrace I am getting:

```
[griffon-pool-1-thread-2] WARN org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.controller.AbstractActionManager - An exception occurred when executing com.softgan.ConductoresController.view
griffon.exceptions.InstanceMethodInvocationException: An error occurred while invoking instance method com.softgan.ConductoresController.view()
    at griffon.util.GriffonClassUtils.invokeExactInstanceMethod(GriffonClassUtils.java:3186)
Caused by: griffon.exceptions.GriffonException: An error occurred while executing a task inside the UI thread
    at com.softgan.ConductoresController.view(ConductoresController.java:122)
    at griffon.util.MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(MethodUtils.java:407)
    at griffon.util.MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(MethodUtils.java:356)
    at griffon.util.GriffonClassUtils.invokeExactInstanceMethod(GriffonClassUtils.java:3182)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: griffon.exceptions.InstanceNotFoundException: Could not find an instance of type com.softgan.VerConductoresView
    ... 4 more
Caused by: griffon.exceptions.InstanceNotFoundException: Could not find an instance of type com.softgan.VerConductoresView
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.softgan.VerConductoresView.<init>(VerConductoresView.java:31)
  while locating com.softgan.VerConductoresView

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1086)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.softgan.AbstractViewPopUp.<init>(AbstractViewPopUp.java:72)
    at com.softgan.VerConductoresView.<init>(VerConductoresView.java:31)
    at com.softgan.VerConductoresView$$FastClassByGuice$$d0c2bde8.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    ... 1 more
[griffon-pool-1-thread-2] ERROR griffon.core.GriffonExceptionHandler - Uncaught Exception. Stacktrace was sanitized. Set System property 'griffon.full.stacktrace' to 'true' for full report.
griffon.exceptions.InstanceMethodInvocationException: An error occurred while invoking instance method com.softgan.ConductoresController.view()
    at griffon.util.GriffonClassUtils.invokeExactInstanceMethod(GriffonClassUtils.java:3186)
Caused by: griffon.exceptions.GriffonException: An error occurred while executing a task inside the UI thread
    at com.softgan.ConductoresController.view(ConductoresController.java:122)
    at griffon.util.MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(MethodUtils.java:407)
    at griffon.util.MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(MethodUtils.java:356)
    at griffon.util.GriffonClassUtils.invokeExactInstanceMethod(GriffonClassUtils.java:3182)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: griffon.exceptions.InstanceNotFoundException: Could not find an instance of type com.softgan.VerConductoresView
    ... 4 more
Caused by: griffon.exceptions.InstanceNotFoundException: Could not find an instance of type com.softgan.VerConductoresView
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.softgan.VerConductoresView.<init>(VerConductoresView.java:31)
  while locating com.softgan.VerConductoresView

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1086)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.softgan.AbstractViewPopUp.<init>(AbstractViewPopUp.java:72)
    at com.softgan.VerConductoresView.<init>(VerConductoresView.java:31)
    at com.softgan.VerConductoresView$$FastClassByGuice$$d0c2bde8.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    ... 1 more
```

**UPDATE**

I already found what the problem was. The constructor was not aware of the loadFromFXML method as in the constructor of the view the UI has not been loaded yet. What I did was simply put the loadFromFXML() inside the init() method of the Abstract Class and call it directly from the Concrete View Class. I found out this by calling the loadFromFXML from the initUI method, which is where the UI can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

AST transformations only apply if you're compiling Groovy code, which may not be what you're doing. The `loadFromFXML()` method expects a resource to be available on the classpath by matching the given argument using the following value transformation

```
arg.replaceAll('.', '/') + ".fxml"
```

This means your code resolves `"com.softgan.viewPopUp"` to `"com/softgan/viewPopUp.fxml"`. Does that file exist in `src/main/resources` or `griffon-app/resources`?

Comment: I have "com.softgan.viewPopUp.fxml" in the resources folder, actually, if I call the loadFromFXML() method from the concrete class extending AbstractViewPopUp I get no error. I get it when I call it directly from the abstract class I created which also extends AbstractJavaFXGriffonView. I might call the loadFromFXML method from every implementation of the AbstractViewPopUp and then maybe save that into a Node object in the super class to pass it as the root of every scene I create for every subclass, but I would prefer it to be loaded within the abstract class.

Comment: I see. Perhaps passing the node to the abstract popup class, such as `super(ObservablePlanilla.class, Conductor.class, loadFromFXML("com.softgan.viewPopUp"));`. I'm assuming line 72 in  `AbstractViewPopUp` points to the invocation of `loadFromFXML` if so I think we're missing stacktrace information

Comment: I think I found the problem. It seems that in the view constructor the view has not been yet initialized, therefore the verConductoresView has no knowledge about the existence of loadFromFXML. I placed loadFromFXML inside the initUI method and everything goes without error, but I am still wondering if there is any way to call the loadFromFXML method within the view constructor. This is like in regular JavaFX when you try to access UI nodes within the constructor and not the initialize method when it has already loaded the UI. If you think of a way of achieving what I ask, please let me know.